# Why in DJANGO the Templates are not updated when I refresh the page with new data in the DB?

Tags: django

The problem is that when I change data through a form or by the django admin if it is saved in the database, but when redirecting to another view or refreshing the screen with f5 it does not show the changes in the user views unless I start session again or delete the cookies, something that for each change you have to perform this operation, however in the django admin views if everything is updated normally with a simple f5.

This is very rare since the page has been working for more than 1 year without this problem and suddenly this happened.

I'm using:

Stevedore

Nginx

gunicorn 20.0.4

Django 3.1.4

python 3.9

sqlite 3

and bootstrap 4.6 for user views

I thought it was just the update of my browser but in any browser the same thing happens

I did not find a similar problem in any forum, I hope you can help me or give me an indication of what is causing this

Comment: Do use caching? It happens to me with caching enabled.

Comment: In setting do not enable any type of cache, should I disable any cache that comes by default?

Comment: from your explanation it seems like your `get` requests been cached. Also caching might happen not only on Django lvl, your dns provider might also cache them.

Comment: Thank you very much, it is the most logical, since a few days ago I changed hosts. and this configuration of the dns cache how could I disable it or is there any way for django to avoid it since in the django admin I don't have that problem only in the user views

Comment: Generally it is a good thing. It means requests are not reaching the django app, thus you can handle much higher load. On the other hand your provider might have a way to invalidate cache.